# What could be a training for a just Saturdays and Sundays?

Tags: running, training, long-distance-running, half-marathon

I don't have much time to do my trainings, I just do my long run on Sundays mornings, but I would like training on Saturdays too, but maybe the training of Saturday could affect my long run of Sundays.. so I would like to know what could be a good 2 consecutive day training per week.
I was thinking of doing a trail running session on Saturday, and Sundays a fartlek in my long run.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't do your long run on Saturday?

Comment: Nop, is it better to do the long run on Saturday, and the trail running on Sunday?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only reason not to practice two days in a row is because the body gets fatigued, and a fatigued body will not have the energy and time to adapt to the training.

How does the body get fatigued?

When you perform one type of training, say long distance running, you are taxing one of several energy systems in your body, specifically, your muscles. In the case of long distance running you are taxing the aerobic system, which utilizes oxygen to make energy for muscle contraction. In the hours after long distance running, your body will undergo changes to prepare for the next session of long distance running with increased functioning. In this time period there will be more harm than good if you do the same training and tax the same system.

To answer your question, one way to circumvent this problem is to tax different energy systems on alternate days. That is, saturday you can do long distance running, while on sundays you can do an anaerobic glycolytic training such as strength training or sprinting.

This way your body will adapt more to the demands put on it, and you will lower the risk of becoming overtrained (Generally speaking. However, this risk is low when practicing 2 times/week).

On an additional note, the energy systems do differ in the time it takes for them to recover. This is exemplified by the phenomenon of supercompensation. Supercompensation is what occurs after the muscle has gotten adequate rest, and also adapted to the increased demand by increaseing fitness temporarily. It is when you practice again, in the time frame of supercompensation, that the body increases its fitness and you become stronger/more endurant. Aerobic training takes less time to regenerate (about 8h for low intencity running), while high-intensity anaerobic glycolytic traning takes longer and thus requires a longer rest period (up to 72h for competitive sprinters and weight lifters).

Comment: Thx u Darko! very helpful your answer..

Comment: The time for the long distance runnning would be 2 hours max? (without streching and warm-up)

Comment: That actually depends on your goals. But lets say that, if you want to increase your aerobic threshold you should be doing 1-6 reps of 10min-2h runs at 60% with 2-3min pause. And for maximum oxygen consumption 8-12 reps of 3-5 min jogs at 80-85% with 2-3min rest.

But as I said, these figures are very generalized and vary between individuals depending on personal factors (age, fitness etc) and goals.

Comment: Also, always warm up before running. Not just before short distance sprinting, but long distance also. Warm ups not only decrease the risk of injury, but also prepares the body for exercise. Make sure you do dynamic stretching before training though. This will help lubricate your joints and loosen up the muscles for a lighter and more biomechanically correct stride. Static stretching only after exercising, as this can actually increase risk of injury.